# How to get the previous day records from mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch previous day records from table but I am not finding how to do it exactly. Need your help please..

Table: RECORD_DATA

```
id       creationDate    
1   | 2013-05-03 04:03:35 |    
2   | 2013-05-03 04:03:35 |
```

Now I need to get all the records that were created on 2013-05-03. Time can be anything. So my query should have LIKE operator.

I am using below query and it gives me empty set.

```
select creationDate from RECORD_DATA 
where creationDate LIKE DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('2012-04-05','%d/%m/%Y'),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fairly simple when done with SQL, just add the condition

```
WHERE creationDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

There is no need to convert creationDate as it is already a date :). And i belive that this will be the fastest way to check it (which will matter if you go over large data sets).

Comment: I would add `AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND` since it seems BETWEEN uses `min <= expr AND expr <= max` according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: This is actually not accurate since it also includes records from current day, not only from previous day

Answer (score 3):

The answers here seem to be answering 'How do I find something within the past 24 hours?', not 'How do I find something from the previous calendar date?'. Different questions.

If you need to find something from the previous calendar date, you can try:

```
select creationDate from RECORD_DATA 
where date(creationDate) = curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

No need to convert dates to strings and do string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD_DATA WHERE `creationDate` >= CURDATE()-1 and `creationDate` < CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will use `INDEX` on `creationDate` (*if there is any*).

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   creationDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
        creationDate < CURDATE()
```

Comment: Correct - But why not use BETWEEN?

Comment: Between is equivalent to `min <= expr AND expr <= max` not `min <= expr AND expr < max` according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM `tableName`
WHERE DAY(created) = DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: DAY is an alias of DAYOFMONTH. DAY('2016-02-01') = DAY('2016-03-01')   = DAY('2016-04-01'), etc. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth