# Current and Previous Day in PHP for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a query which should only return data for the current day and want to use end time and start time.

Something like this.

```
$endtime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$starttime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s") - 1; // Not working..


$sql = "select * from tbl_order where transdate between $starttime and $endtime";
```

Can you please help?

RJ

Comment: `date(transdate)=CURDATE() `??

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16372608/689579

Comment: @Dagon between a single point in time ?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин no that's a whole day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you try to achieve, but if you want to get the orders from the past 24 hours (note: not the last day), this will do:

```
$endtime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$starttime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", (time() - (60*60*24)));
```

Although I would say it is neater to do this with pure SQL.

Comment: if this is what hew wanted then the pure sql version is : `transdate > NOW()-interval 1 day`

Answer (score 0):

The `between` keyword operates on date values, not on strings.

```
<?php
$jan = '2014-01';
$feb = '2014-02';
$sql = "select record_ts from table where date(record_ts) 
        between str_to_date('$jan', '%Y-%m')
            and str_to_date('$feb', '%Y-%m');
       ";
?>
```

Notice that I have to convert record_ts to a (MySQL) date because the column is defined as a time stamp, I also have to convert the date-strings.

## . . .

Carl Maskham, your comment may be valid for recent versions of MySQL.

```
mysql> select record_ts from table where date(record_ts)
       between '2014-01'
           and '2014-02' ; 
Empty set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> select record_ts from table where date(record_ts) 
        between str_to_date('2014-01', '%Y-%m')
            and str_to_date('2014-02', '%Y-%m');
(...)
1119 rows in set (0.01 sec)

$ mysql --version 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.70, for pc-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: [I beg to differ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) Between will work on any numerical value and singular strings.